# Efficient way to create nested objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

**Are there any more efficient ways to create nested objects than nested `for` approach?**

I am trying to hold 25 random numbers (1 - 71), 5 row x 5 column. I will iterate through each item to check if ballPicker() function (not yet implemented) has picked a number that the object has. So I need to keep the information that if a number was found. I could have done it with a 5 x 5 array but iterating that array will not be as efficient as objects.

I have an array starting from 1 to 71 (inclusive, step is 1).
I shuffle the array in createRandomNumberArray() function. So shuffledNumbers array values are not sequential

```
let shuffledNumbers = Array.from({length: 71}, (v, i) => i + 1);

function createRandomNumberArray() {     //Fisher - Yates shuffle algorithm
    let randomPosition;
    let temp;
    for (let i = shuffledNumbers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = shuffledNumbers[i];
        shuffledNumbers[i] = shuffledNumbers[randomPosition];
        shuffledNumbers[randomPosition] = temp;
    }
}
```

In createBoards() function I am creating an object (board) that holds 5 objects (row) with their indexes as property name. And row has 5 objects (cell) with their indexes as property name again. Cell has only one object that gets its property name from slicedArray(slicedArray is a 5 item slice from shuffledNumbers that holds non duplicated random numbers (range inclusive 1 to inclusive 71)) and its value is always false.

```
function createBoards() {
    let board = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let row = {};
        let slicedArray = shuffledNumbers.slice((i * 5), ((i + 1) * 5));
        for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            let cell = {};
            cell[slicedArray[j]] = false;
            row[j] = cell;
        }
        board[i] = row;
    }
    return board;
}
```

I want to keep the structure like this:

[image: The structure that I am getting with my code (using WebStorm)]

Board object will have exactly 5 rows and 1 row has exactly 5 items. And in the future I need to iterate those items to find the random value that I had assigned before. I thought it is faster to use objects than arrays. I hope I am correct.

Comment: If you got continuous indexes as keys, it certainly makes sense to use a real array ...

Comment: @JonasWilms I am trying to hold 25 items in one board object. I could have used 5 x 5 array but I need to keep information that if ballPicker() (not yet implemented) function picked a ball that exists in the board. Basically a bingo game. And I think iterating through a 5 x 5 array is slower than objects

Comment: there is no difference betweem `obj[5][6]` and `array[5][6]`